# GPU/CUDA volume and SSS support

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

As my fedora repos are way behind and still on blender 2.69, I've gone and compiled the latest myself. Everything seems to work and is quite recent. I can even bake CPU SSS, which is great. However I still get the error "**Volumes/SSS not supported on GPU**". Have I missed a flag or library (eg OSL support) in CMAKE or is this still on the todo list? If its just not finished yet, I don't mean to rush the devs but definitely looking forward to its release.

Comment: The official Windows version of 2.70a does not support it, and the [cycles release notes of 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles) do not mention it either. I guess you still have to wait for that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, these features aren't finished yet.

## SSS

GPU SSS is working, but still experimental.
To test it, you need to [add one line in the `kernel_types` header file](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-cycles/2014-February/001820.html):

```
diff --git a/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_types.h b/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_types.h
index 8d7adb2..1175c16 100644
--- a/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_types.h
+++ b/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_types.h
@@ -66,6 +66,7 @@ CCL_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
 #ifdef __KERNEL_CUDA__
 #define __KERNEL_SHADING__
 #define __KERNEL_ADV_SHADING__
+#define __SUBSURFACE__
 #define __BRANCHED_PATH__
 //#define __VOLUME__
 #endif
```

It seems the main reason that this isn't yet included as  an *experimental feature* is that [it requires compiling kernels twice](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-cycles/2013-December/001702.html):

> we cannot make it available just under experimental, we would need to compile all kernels 2x (for each architecture).

### Update:

GPU SSS is enabled in master as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBfb3f32760d68134aadb7978922360857f0ecccb7). Now any new development build will have SSS on GPU. This will be in 2.72.

## Volumetrics

Volume support for GPU was unofficially working shortly after its addition (see `2:22` of this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc17UHz9SVA)), however broke with the addition of scattering (see `2:50` of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnY-NjUPQWE)).

According to the [same video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnY-NjUPQWE), GPU volumetrics was supposed to be fixed for 2.70. Since that was not the case, I can only assume that development was delayed and it's still due to be fixed at some point.

### update:

GPU volume support has been added to master as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB8d0b3e9902540a354b633c854f0fa83a0c839dfd), but currently is in a very experimental state and smoke/fire renders are not supported yet. This will be in 2.72.

Comment: oh its so fast and deliciously pretty. thank you for all the info and links!! I'll be keeping an eye out for volumetrics next

Comment: @jozxyqk GPU Volumetrics are here now :)